# Меню поверх всего

Tags: html, css, php

Здраствуйте. Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой. Имеется выпадающее меню с подсписками и слайдер находящийся прямо под меню. Так вот, когда меню открывается, его подсписков не видно, так как слайдер закрывает их.

http://www.soccerpro.com/ - здесь сделано так как надо. Прошу помощи. Заранее премного благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z-index Вам в помощь. И не забудьте установить для меню position.